# IOS 5 compatibility using Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, xcode8

I have an app in appstore supporting from ios8 and later. But one of my client neeed to run it in ios 5.1.1 ipad too . Is it possible to submit apps in appstore having ios 5.x compatible versios ? How can i make it compatible with ios 5.x ?

Comment: not possible.....

Comment: Do you ***really*** have to support that version, iOS 5.1.1 is sooo f--- old, it will be a **massive** pain for you to support it (if at all possible). iOS 5 lacks soo many features.

Comment: Show your client this link https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/ . Only 8% devices are iOS < 9, and supporting devices less than iOS 7 is non sense because that will require a lot of hard work which is not worth it since the number of users are very very less

Answer (score 3):

Not his is not possible, iOS 5.1.1 supports device with ARM v6 processor. Which is no longer supported by Xcode. 
You will therefor need an older copy of Xcode, with the iOS 5.1.1 SDK.

The bige problem is that you will then not be able to submit your app to the Appstore since this requires you to build with the iOS 9 SDK.

You might be able to remove the ARM v6 slice from the binary you compiled with the older version of Xcode and add that slice to you new binary, but you will run into many more issues.

The cheapest is to buy this client an new iPad.